# open html file inside div after being created by the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, servlets

I have build up a webapp where on button click, a servlet is called `via ajax` which creates a `html file` within the directory in context path.

Now, after the ajax call is completed, I need to open that html file inside my div `diffReport`.

Here is the script which i have written

```
$(document).on('click', '#detect', function() {
var url = document.getElementById("url").value;

$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
      $("#loader").show();
});
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    $("#loader").hide();
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'diffReport?url='+url,
    success:function(data){
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : data,
            success : function(msg) {
                $('#diffReport').html(msg);

            }

        });
    }
   });
});
```

And my div

```
<div id="diffReport" style="width:45.5%; height: 730px;float:right">
            <p>Diff report will load here....</p>
            <span id="loader">please wait..<br><img alt="loading..." src="resources/images/loader.gif"></span>
</div>
```

And this is how I am passing the path of html file created

```
File reportDir = AutoUtils.createDirectory(contextPath+"/resources/htmlreports/");

DiffGenerator.createHtml(someParams,reportDir.getAbsolutePath());  //this creates file with name 'finalDiff.html'

response.getWriter().write(reportDir.getAbsolutePath()+"/finalDiff.html");  //copy the file path in response.
```

But nothing is loaded after `ajaxStop`. There's no error on console even.

Please suggest.

Comment: Try to add error function and check the response (pay attention on mime type). Also, I recommend your to look what data is inside the response. Use Fiddler or Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug.

Comment: You have said that you want to open the newly created file, so do you want to open that html file into a dynamically created iframe ? If you just want to dynamically add an <a> tag with a link to the new file, I can provide a solution to that !

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for this. I assume that you are successful in getting the full url of the newly created html page through ajax. For example, I suppose that the url of your newly created html file is "http://jsfiddle.net/" and this page will be loaded into the div through the iframe. I have created a **demo [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/yrC2E/1/)** for that :

HTML :

```
<div id="iframe_div">
</div>
```

JS:

```
//url of newly created html file
var file_src = "http://jsfiddle.net/";

$('<iframe>')                      // Creates the element
.attr('src',file_src) // Sets the src attribute 
.attr('height',500)
.attr('width',500)
.appendTo('#iframe_div');
```

Comment: Yeah, iframe did the trick. I already have implemented the solution.